# How to generate a CSV from text files using shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to write data from three txt files in csv file.

three files contain below data

data in the file is in this format -server date filename number

first txt file as-

```
app1 11.12.16 name1 2
app1 11.12.17 name2 3
```

second as

```
app2 11.12.16 name1 2
app2 11.12.17 name2 3
```

and same for thrird file with server as app3

i want to put this data from these three files to one csv file using shell script. the data in the txt file is separated with space.

data should go in same manner just in different row.

One more thing can be put a heading in the first row as server date filename number and put filter? is it possible?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What do you mean by "just in different row"?

Comment: are you just asking to combine 3 files into 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way to do it:

```
(
    echo "server,date,filename,number"; sed 's/\s\+/,/g' file*
) >target.csv
```

This doesn't reorder rows, though.

Comment: Don't even need the for loop, just `sed 's/\s\+/,/g' file* > out.csv`

Comment: Nice one! Didn't know that (didn't read the manpage enough). Edited!

Comment: you don't need the `echo` either: `sed 's/\s\+/,/g;1i server,date,filename,number' file*`

Comment: Meh, I don't know sed that much, as you probably have figured out ;) I prefer the echo way for clarity reasons but will remind that `i` command though.

Comment: one thing more can we add filter functionality also...is iot possible?

Comment: like we make it in excel at header we select a auto filter...can we make it in csv...

Comment: No, this is not possible and you will have to rely on your spreadsheet program for that. A CSV just defines a storage format.

Comment: whenever next file is selected this part always comes.. "server,date,filename,number" ex: server,date,filename,number                                         app1,date,abc,3 app1,date,adc,4 server,date,filename,number app2,date,abc,4....so on... is there any way to have server,date,filename,number just once at the top only....